# Get data into a format for xgboost in R?

Tags: r, xgboost

Does someone have a very well-explained example of getting data into a format usable by xgboost in R?

The [get started doc](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/doc/get_started/index.md) doesn't help me. The data (`agaricus.train` and `agaricus.test`) are already in a specialized format (`dgCMatrix`):

```
> str(agaricus.train)
List of 2
 $ data :Formal class 'dgCMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 6 slots
  .. ..@ i       : int [1:143286] 2 6 8 11 18 20 21 24 28 32 ...
  .. ..@ p       : int [1:127] 0 369 372 3306 5845 6489 6513 8380 8384 10991 ...
  .. ..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 6513 126
  .. ..@ Dimnames:List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:126] "cap-shape=bell" "cap-shape=conical" "cap-shape=convex" "cap-shape=flat" ...
  .. ..@ x       : num [1:143286] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  .. ..@ factors : list()
 $ label: num [1:6513] 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
```

I saw [this example code](https://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/482990/xgboost-example/) use [sparse.model.matrix](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Matrix/versions/1.2-8/topics/sparse.model.matrix), but I'm still having a hard time putting together fairly plain data into the format xgboost needs.

For example, suppose I have two data frames: `words` and `labels`.

The `words` data frame has `sentence_id` and `word_id`, with one or more words per sentence.

The `data_label` data frame has a sentence_id and label (say, 0 or 1 for a binary classification task).

How do I get that data into a format to predict the label for a sentence?

I can split train and test.

**Edit**: The simplest version of words and data_label:

```
words <- data.frame(sentence_id=c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
                    word_id=c(1, 2, 1, 3, 4))
data_label <- data.frame(sentence_id=c(1, 2), label=c(0, 1))
```

Comment: Need [MCVE] to begin coding.

Comment: I am guessing that you know how to convert your data frame into the matrix format that is essential for xgboost and that all your data is in numeric format. Can you post a small sample of your data and the code you are using otherwise it is not clear what the problem may be.

Comment: @cousin_pete I put code for words and data_label above.

Comment: @42- I put code for words and data_label above.

Comment: @cousin_pete  Let's not assume I know how to convert to matrix format. There are several different conversion functions, and I don't know which xgboost wants.

Comment: I am a bit bust at the moment but check an answer I gave with some example code that you may be able to adapt: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41816754/stop-xgboost-based-on-eval-metric/41841946#41841946

Answer (score 2):

Input to `xgb.DMatrix` could be either dense `matrix`, or sparse `dgCMatrix`, or sparse data stored in a file in LibSVM format. Since you are dealing with textual data, the sparse representation would be the most appropriate.
Below is an example of how to convert your example data to dgCMatrix.
Here I was assuming a perfect situation with continuous sets of integer sentence_id's starting from 1 that are the same in both tables. If it would not be so in practice, some more data munging on your part would be needed.

```
library(Matrix)

words <- data.frame(sentence_id=c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
                    word_id=c(1, 2, 1, 3, 4))
data_label <- data.frame(sentence_id=c(1, 2), label=c(0, 1))

# quick check of assumptions about sentence_id
stopifnot(min(words$sentence_id) == 1 &&
          max(words$sentence_id) == length(unique(words$sentence_id)))

# sparse matrix construction from "triplet" data
# (rows are sentences, columns are words, and the value is always 1)
smat <- sparseMatrix(i = words$sentence_id, j = words$word_id, x = 1)

# make sure sentence_id are in proper order in data_label:
data_label <- data_label[order(data_label$sentence_id)]
stopifnot(all.equal(data_label$sentence_id, 1:nrow(smat)))

xmat <- xgb.DMatrix(smat, label = data_label$label)
```